# How to add borders to WPF ListView in code

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview, wpf-controls

I have created a ListView with a GridView in code.

```
ListView gridList = new ListView();
GridView gridListView = new GridView ();
gridList.View = gridListView;
```

Now, I define a GridViewColumn, set the header, width and bindingPath. All good and the data shows up.

```
GridViewColumn listColumn = new GridViewColumn();
listColumn.Header = "Some Header";
listColumn.Width = 100.0;
listColumn.DisplayMemeberBinding = new Binding("Name");
gridListView.Columns.Add(listColumn);
```

But there are no borders/gridlines shown on display of this ListView. How can I add borders through code?

Someone described my exact problem here but no good solution mentioned
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fa4fa8e0-81fe-487a-8763-590062d29c06/wpf-listview-gridview-row-border?forum=wpf

Comment: delete all that and use proper XAML.

Comment: I cannot use XAML since I have to dynamically create this control which gets rendered to an XPS file.

Answer (score 1):

The logic in WPF programming is totally different from what you've done in winforms. Everything related to UI should always be set up using XAML (as much as possible). The WPF library itself has many parts desgined mainly for use in XAML although there is always an equivalent codebehind. However that's when using codebehind may be awkward and non-intuitive (as well as straight-forward).

I understand that you want something like the ListView Grid in Winforms. In WPF that can be achieved easily if you use XAML code. Even in code behind, you can always build a `Style` or `Template` from XAML string (with the help of `XamlReader`). This approach is good for complex scenario but in this case I have another approach (don't use the XAML parser at all). This trick does render the grid which is good enough (and at best it can do for the trade-off of simplicity):

```
//we need an instance of Style to set to ListView.ItemContainerStyle
var style = new Style(typeof(ListViewItem));
//set the bottom border thickness to 1
var setter = new Setter(Control.BorderThickness, new Thickness(0,0,0,1));
style.Setters.Add(setter);
//set the border brush
var borderBrush = new LinearGradientBrush { StartPoint = new Point(0,0),
                                            EndPoint = new Point(1,0)};
var gradStop = new GradientStop(Colors.Transparent, 0.001);
    borderBrush.GradientStops.Add(gradStop);
gradStop = new GradientStop(Colors.Green, 0.001);
    borderBrush.GradientStops.Add(gradStop);
gradStop = new GradientStop(Colors.Green, 0.999);
    borderBrush.GradientStops.Add(gradStop);
gradStop = new GradientStop(Colors.Transparent, 0.999);
    borderBrush.GradientStops.Add(gradStop);
setter = new Setter(Control.BorderBrush, borderBrush);
style.Setters.Add(setter);

yourListView.ItemContainerStyle = style;
```

Note that the default inner `Border` of each `ListViewItem` has a hard-coded `CornerRadius` of about 2, so by setting just the bottom `BorderBrush` to a solid brush such as `Brushes.Green` will show a little upwards curly line at the 2 ends of the bottom border. You can try it yourself. If this result is acceptable, the code can be shorter and simpler (because you don't have to define the `GradientBrush` to cut-off the 2 curly ends) like this:

```
setter = new Setter(Control.BorderBrush, Brushes.Green);
style.Setters.Add(setter);
```

If the behavior is still not what you want. You should try the approach I mentioned about using `XamlReader` to parse a XAML string and get an instance of whatever you want in codebehind. (you can search it yourself, it's easy to have some result).

Comment: Hey, thanks a bunch for mentioning this method. I am not able to get the horizontal grid lines in my GridView now. I need to get the vertical lines as well to complete the look. I checked the GridViewColumn and it only has styling for the header not for the indivisual cells. Do you know how the vertical lines for every column can be obtained through code?

Comment: @NikhilNehriya The code in my answer just renders horizontal lines and in fact it's some kind of hack/play with (fake) border. However for vertical lines, doing something like that is hard to achieve. It's nearly impossible to have an elegant work-around solving this issue. You can try play with `GridViewColumn.CellTemplate`. Changing the `CellTemplate` seems to be the only way but even changing that template, the result is still not very perfect. The problem is there is always a space (some kind of cell-spacing) between the cells.

Comment: Ya I was toying with the CellTemplate but the results weren't ideal. Was wondering if you knew of a better way around that. It is a bit strange that such basic customizations are missing from the WPF world. Anyway I now have the horizontal lines thanks to your answer. Will make do with that.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you see this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/grid-in-wpf/), it contains a dynamic GridView created in code-behind that can be useful for your specific case. For the code sample that you provided, you didn't add ShowGridLines property.

Comment: Thanks, but in my case I am using a ListView and the link you have provided uses a Grid. I have everything I need exception I am missing the gridlines. Also, ShowGridLines property is for the Grid class not the ListView class :-(